# wp_get_attachment_url generates different links

Tags: wordpress

I write this code for get all attachments of a post:

```
$args = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $pid,
    'exclude'    => $exclude,
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'    => null,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);


foreach($attachments as $at)
{
    ?>
    <li> <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($at->ID); ?>"><?php echo $at->post_title; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

For `.zip` or `.xlsx` file types it generate a url like this:

http://localhost/mywp/wp-contents/uploads/test.zip (it's ok)

But for `.docx` file types it generate a url like this:

http://localhost/mywp/?attachment_id=710
(This link not work (download) for me.)

What is problem?

Comment: Does the docx file have any invalid characters in the name?

Comment: @DerekNolan Thanks. i have mime type error!!

Answer (score 1):

My problem is in Ajax upload!! `wp_handle_upload` have error. (mime type error) and `wp_insert_attachment` insert empty record. and cause to create wrong link.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [get_attachment_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link) ? Here is the sample code

```
$attachment_id = 1; // ID of attachment
$attachment_page = get_attachment_link( $attachment_id ); 
?>
<a href="<?php echo $attachment_page; ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $attachment_id ); ?></a>
```